# Make a power BI Report in auto focus mode automatically

Tags: angular, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a simple Microsoft Power BI example in which the list of employee are grouped by gender.

```
  <iframe width="300" height="200" src="https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=******" ></iframe>
```

My probleme is that my div is not so big (muste be like that ) so the report is not clear but it is clear when i choose auto focus.
So can i make it directly or automatically in the auto focus mode?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
iframe.onblur = function() {
  iframe.focus();
}
```

OR

```
<iframe id="iframe" autofocus="true"  width="300" height="200" src="https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=******" ></iframe>
<script>
    document.getElementById('iframe').focus();
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not working. I diidn't mention that earlier ,i'm working with angular.